# ¿Es posible enviar email a través de Cloud9?

Tags: email, cloud9

Estoy usando **Cloud9** para desarrollar un plugin para Wordpress, pero a la hora de usar las funciones `wp_mail()` y `mail()` nunca recibo los correos.

¿Sabéis si **Cloud9** bloquea el envío de correos?

Comment: esto te puede ayudar también: https://community.c9.io/t/cant-send-email-from-workspace/4850/5

Comment: Si te bloquea, podrías ocupar un servicio externo como mailgun

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo su foro de ayuda indican que sí bloquea los mensajes de correo para evitar *spammers*.

En [este hilo](https://community.c9.io/t/how-can-i-send-email-from-my-app/1262) te ofrecen la respuesta y posibles soluciones para el envío de correo.